# rm index.html shows no such file or directory

Tags: kali-linux

I am running Kali Linux 2017.2 amd 64, when I used the command rm index.html ,it shows no such file or directory.Before this command, I used the command" cd /var/www". Kindly,help me with this issue as I am striving hard because I don't have basic background knowledge of Kali/Ubuntu .

Comment: I think this is the perfect opportunity to link to this...[Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: You seem to be struggling with very basic Linux functionality. Please do yourself a favour and try a Linux tutorial at the very least before attempting anything with Kali.